# Column Encryption Setting=enabled not working in Linked Service (Azure Data Factory)

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, always-encrypted

I'm trying to implement a Custom Dot Net Activity which performs a stored procedure activity.

I've known that ADF already having a build in `StoredProcActivity`. But I want to insert into a table which has been already encrypted (using Always Encryption provider as the Azure Key Vault)

To workaround with always, Encryption using Azure Key vault requires the connection string to be like [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/develop-using-always-encrypted-with-net-framework-data-provider)

The thing I struct is the simple one While creating a `AzureSqlLinkedService`. I've added to my connection string with the `Column Encryption Setting=enabled` aalue. Actually, my connection string would be like:

```
Data Source=tcp:<ServerNAme>.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=<DBName>;User ID=<UserName>@<ServerNAme>;Password=<Password>;Integrated Security=False;Encrypt=True;Connect Timeout=30;Column Encryption Setting=enabled;
```

But, I got an error

> Entity provisioning failed: Failed to connect to Linked service. Specified connection string is not valid.

Comment: So the question here, does ADF support the use of encrypted linked service?

Comment: Indirect yes .. no msdn sites told that adf doesn't support encrypted linked service

Comment: Good question. I'd be keen to know the answer.